# php pie chart with count function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, charts, pie-chart

**I want to create a piechart image which is populated from data from mysql.**

**Example**:

```
imagefilledarc($image ,125 ,125 , 200, 200, 0, 180, $navy, IMG_ARC_PIE);
imagefilledarc($image ,125 ,125 , 200, 200, 180, 360, $red, IMG_ARC_PIE);
```

- That would produce a pie chart image split 50:50.
- But i want the pie chart to use data from the database
- I want to count the number of events in this particular team and then display it on the pie chart.
- Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

  **Code:**

  ```
         <?php
          include( "./inc/header.inc.php");
          include ("./inc/connect.inc.php"); 
          ?>
          <?php
          $TeamName = "";
          $TeamID = "";
                  }
          else
          {

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT MatchEventID) FROM MatchEvent WHERE TeamID = '9' AND EventID ='7'");
  $count = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  $pass = $count[0];
  }
          }

          //create image
          $image = imagecreatetruecolor(250,250);
          $white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
          imagefill($image, 0, 0, $white);

          //allocate some colour
          $white = imagecolorallocate($image, 0xFF , 0xFF, 0xFF);
          $gray = imagecolorallocate($image, 0xC0 , 0xC0, 0xC0);
          $darkgray = imagecolorallocate($image, 0x90 , 0x90, 0x90);
          $navy = imagecolorallocate($image, 0x00 , 0x00, 0x80);
          $darknavy = imagecolorallocate($image, 0x00 , 0x00, 0x05);
          $red = imagecolorallocate($image, 0xFF , 0x00, 0x00);
          $darkred = imagecolorallocate($image, 0x90, 0x00, 0x00);

          imagefilledarc($image ,125 ,125 , 200, 200, 0, $pass, $navy, IMG_ARC_PIE);
          imagefilledarc($image ,125 ,125 , 200, 200, $pass, 360, $red, IMG_ARC_PIE);

          //flush image
          header('Content-type: image/png');
          imagepng($image);
          //imagedestroy($image);
          ?>
  ```

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there isn't a question asked.

Comment: I was wondering how i go about doing it and why doesnt that code work etc

Comment: 'pass' is from $result and not from $Test. you must fetch the result from $result for the $pass value.

Comment: could you please elaborate sorry im new to this

Comment: ive edited the code since i first put it up

Comment: you are doing $arr = mysql_fetch_array($Test) to get $TeamID from your $Test query. to get $pass from your $result query you have to fetch from $result (like: $row = mysql_fetch_array($result)). using $pass = $arr['pass'] is wrong, because $arr fetch from $Test and where is no 'pass' value.

Comment: Thank for the help, the code is edited since then and still isnt working any suggestions?

Comment: try: $pass = intval($count[0]); for: $pass = $count[0];

Comment: thanks no it doesnt work. I took away all the sql part and changed it to $pass = 60. This doesn't work yet if i enter 60 in to the imagefilledarc part it works fine. I can't understand why it wont accept a variable

Comment: @ingwy Thanks its all working now